# passphrase after login -f username in terminal osx

Tags: macos, terminal, atom-editor

After opening a terminal and attempt to log in to ssh my OS X remember passphrase but when I use "login -f username".... I have to enter passphrase manually. Even if I type "sudo -s" after "login -f username", terminal ask me about root password instead of passphrase.

Why? There is no way to do this automatically?

I try to use Atom with term2 package. With normal configuration I can't use git commands. So I add autoRunCommand: 'login -f username' to config. git works... but can't login to VPS because always big passphrase have to be inserted manually. I'm on OS X, Atom term2 (terminal in Atom) and ssh is for VPS Ubuntu Server on Digital Ocean.

Comment: Which machine are you sting into?

Comment: I try to use Atom with term2 package. With normal configuration I can't use git commands. So I add autoRunCommand: 'login -f username' to config. git works... but can't login to VPS because always big passphrase have to be inserted manually.

I'm on OS X, Atom term2 (terminal in Atom) and ssh is for VPS Ubuntu Server on Digital Ocean.

Comment: Please put that and make it clear in the question - what has git to do with this

Comment: @Mark I try to set Atom as my main file editor. With term2 package I can have in one window terminal and project files. git commands I use in that terminal while working on projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add -p to login command :)

Comment: That's it! Thank's for help!